# Spring boot: exchange for getForEntity

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-rest

I'd like to know whether it could be written using `getforEntity` instead of `exchange`:

```
ResponseEntity<List<String>> response = this.restTemplate
    .exchange(
        this.backOfficeProperties.getFrontOfficeUrl(),
        HttpMethod.GET,
        null,
        new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>(){}
    );
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your correctly you need to use the following construction. I know that is not the same as List but unfortunately there is no another way to use getForEntity

```
ResponseEntity<Object[]> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(his.backOfficeProperties.getFrontOfficeUrl(), Object[].class);
Object[] objects = responseEntity.getBody();
```